# How to save time when combing two or more graphs in Networkx

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, networkx

We are working on Blockchain data and running the codes in Python Jupyter Notebook right now. I found there was no such union function about merging two graphs in `networkx` so I just merged manually.
Since there might be self-loops and multiple edges in a graph and common nodes in both graphs, I first created two graphs separately and then extracted nodes and edges from these two graphs and then created the union of unique nodes and all the edges in two graphs. After that, I created a new larger graph using the union nodes and edges. 
Due to the total 26 million data, I spent about 30 min on creating each graph and 30 min on creating the union edges and nodes.
Creating two weeks’ graph from the union edges and nodes takes 56 min. As such, the whole process of creating two weeks’ graph using union function needs about 120 min. 
Since it took such a long time when we just tested with 2 weeks data, we believe it will be a total nightmare to deal with several months of data.I was wondering if these are other ways can help us to save much more time and memory when running the codes.Here is the code:

**Creating two graphs separately, spent 30min for each graph**

```
edges_week2 = [tuple(x) for x in week2.to_records(index=False)]
df1 = week2.stack().reset_index(drop=True, level=1).reset_index(name='Nodes')
nodes0 = df1['Nodes'].tolist()
nodes_week2 = list(set(nodes0))

G_week1 = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G_week1.add_nodes_from(nodes_week1)
G_week1.add_edges_from(edges_week1)
G_week2 = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G_week2.add_nodes_from(nodes_week2)
G_week2.add_edges_from(edges_week2)
```

**Creating the union edges and nodes, spent 30 min**

```
week_union_nodes=list(set(list(G_week1.nodes)+list(G_week2.nodes)))
week_union_edges=list(list(G_week1.edges())+list(G_week2.edges()))
```

**Creating two weeks’ graph from the union edges and nodes takes 56 min**

```
G_week_union=nx.MultiDiGraph()
G_week_union.add_nodes_from(week_union_nodes)
G_week_union.add_edges_from(week_union_edges)
```

Comment: There is a union function.  https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/operators.html

Comment: If that code doesn't do what you want, it will be helpful to see what you've tried.  Otherwise we don't know if the suggestions we might make are faster than what you're already trying.

Comment: I know the union function but it needs these two graphs to be disjoint, sorry about that. Is there any ways to deal with this situation? @Joel

Comment: I think then the function you could use is `compose`.

Comment: You already have `nodes_week1` and `nodes_week2`.  You don't need to go back to recreate `list(G_week1.nodes)` and `list(G_week2.nodes)`

Comment: You also don't need to turn the sum of the two lists into a set and then a list again.  networkx is fine with repeated nodes.  So you could just take the sum of the two lists.  networkx is also fine receiving a set of nodes as opposed to a list, so your final step to turn it back into a set is also unneeded.

Comment: Unless you actually need to use the two graphs for the different weeks for something, you don't need to create them in order to create the combined graph.

Comment: I tried with compose command and it doesn't perform well when there are multiple edges in both graphs. I tested with some baby example. I created G1 and G2 and G used the same method as I posted and used "compose" to create the graph T and Q.@Joel

Comment: I printed all the edges of graphs, ('T:', [(2, 8, 0), (2, 5, 0), (2, 6, 0), (3, 3, 0), (3, 4, 0), (3, 5, 0), (3, 6, 0), (3, 7, 0), (4, 8, 0), (4, 5, 0), (4, 5, 1), (4, 5, 2), (4, 7, 0), (5, 6, 0), (6, 8, 0), (6, 2, 0), (6, 3, 0), (6, 7, 0)])
('Q:', [(2, 8, 0), (2, 5, 0), (2, 6, 0), (3, 3, 0), (3, 4, 0), (3, 5, 0), (3, 6, 0), (3, 7, 0), (4, 8, 0), (4, 5, 0), (4, 5, 1), (4, 5, 2), (4, 7, 0), (5, 6, 0), (6, 8, 0), (6, 2, 0), (6, 3, 0), (6, 7, 0)])@Joel

Comment: ('G:',[(2, 8, 0), (2, 5, 0), (2, 6, 0), (3, 3, 0), (3, 4, 0), (3, 5, 0), (3, 6, 0), (3, 7, 0), (4, 8, 0), (4, 5, 0), (4, 5, 1), (4, 5, 2), (4, 5, 3), (4, 5, 4), (4, 7, 0), (5, 6, 0), (5, 6, 1), (6, 8, 0), (6, 2, 0), (6, 3, 0), (6, 7, 0)])
('G1:', [(3, 3, 0), (3, 4, 0), (3, 5, 0), (3, 6, 0), (3, 7, 0), (4, 5, 0), (4, 5, 1), (4, 5, 2), (4, 7, 0), (5, 6, 0), (6, 3, 0), (6, 7, 0)])
('G2:',[(2, 8, 0), (2, 5, 0), (2, 6, 0), (4, 8, 0), (4, 5, 0), (4, 5, 1), (5, 6, 0), (6, 8, 0), (6, 2, 0)])@Joel

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Joel! I will use the nodes_week1 and nodes_week2 to replace list(G_week1.nodes) and  list(G_week2.nodes).@Joel

Comment: I think I still need to turn the sum of the two lists into a set and then a list again cause I need to get the unique edges otherwise I will run into the name clash if I have duplicate nodes. Be free to see this example:
union_nodes=list(set(list(G1.nodes)+list(G2.nodes)))
print(union_nodes)
union_nodes_test=list(G1.nodes)+list(G2.nodes)
print(union_nodes_test)
union_nodes=list(set(list(G1.nodes)+list(G2.nodes)))
union_nodes_test=list(G1.nodes)+list(G2.nodes)
print(union_nodes); print(union_nodes_test)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 4, 5, 6] @Joel